# Windows 10 - Start Items wont show

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

[image: http://i.imgur.com/yysa2ew.png]

As you can see everything on the left fails to show for some reason.

Comment: Upgrade to Version 1607 your still using version 1511

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The startmenu shows up fine, but you disabled the options to show the most used apps and the last installed apps

[image]

To undo this, [open the Settings app](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/6460-start-menu-most-used-apps-add-remove-windows-10-a.html), go to Personalization -> Start and activate here the options to show both again:

[image]

Comment: Surprisingly - This actually is turned on and its still not doing anything :/

Comment: turn them off and on again